# How to automaticly refresh a view with a trigger in Oracle 11g?

Tags: database, view, oracle11g, triggers

I have a table

```
STORE (ID, NAME, CITY_ID)` and a table `CITY (ID, NAME)`
```

and a view

```
CITY_STORE (CITY_ID, CITY_NAME, COUNT_STORES)
```

I have created a view `V_CITY_STORE` where I have a column which shows the count of the stores in a particular city, `COUNT_STORES (COUNT(STORE.ID))`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_CITY_STORE AS
SELECT C.ID CITY_ID, C.NAME CITY_NAME, COUNT(S.ID) COUNT_STORES 
FROM CITY C
LEFT JOIN STORE S ON S.CITY = C.ID
GROUP BY C.ID, C.NAME;
```

I want to create a trigger which will automatically update the count of the stores for each city when some store is updated, deleted or a new store is inserted.

I tried to make a trigger in which I refreshed the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_CITY_STORE
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON STORE
BEGIN
REPLACE VIEW V_CITY_STORE AS
SELECT C.ID CITY_ID, C.NAME CITY_NAME, COUNT(S.ID) COUNT_STORES 
FROM CITY C
LEFT JOIN STORE S ON S.CITY = C.ID
GROUP BY C.ID, C.NAME;
END;
```

But this returns me an error - I suppose that I cannot have a view inside a trigger. I am quite new to triggers and procedures, I learnt them for only 2 days.

How can I do this?

Comment: A view is just a stored query... why do you think you need to recreate it when data it's querying changes? Including the error you got is always helpful, but you also can't do DDL in a trigger anyway as it commits (unless you make it autonomous, but don't), and there isn't a `replace view` statement... You whole premise seems flawed though. Or am I missing something?

Comment: A view stores no data (unless it's a materialized view).  Each time the view is called, it queries the tables and generates the counts etc.  So as data changes in the tables, so does the data in the views.  However, a materialized view would need to be refreshed, but that doesn't seem to be what you're using.  So that being said, just call the view again to get "refreshed" data no need to regenerate the View.

Comment: Alex Poole: thank you, good to know! Well as it exists a statement "Create or replace view" I just put the "create" away :D So I would just make "Create or replace view" statement where the name of the view is the same but with different Select, right? I think now I get this problem.

xQbert: Yeah, you are right. How would I make the refreshing when it was a materialized view, then?

Answer (score 0):

If stores are rarely updated, deleted, or inserted, then it *might* be acceptable to do what you say you want to do. In which case, an autonomous transaction in the body of an after statement trigger might be acceptable and will allow you to re-materialize the view.

However, if there is any doubt about about how rare such events are or if you don't want to create a brittle system (which it will surely be), then I recommend you go to the project sponsor and negotiate the amount of time between refreshes of the materialized view. Under such circumstances you would create a dbms_scheduler job that would perform the task.

Comment: It doesn't say it's a *materialized* view. And if it was you'd use a normal refresh mechanism, not a trigger to force a refresh?

Comment: Based on how the question is phrased, it is likely something he wants to do but in my second paragraph I discourage him from doing so.